# Camera plugged into raspberry pi timing out when taking pictures

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I have a camera plugged into a USB port on my raspberry pi. It is capable of taking about 3-5 pictures before I get this message:

Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.

I have the resolution set at 320x240. I have gotten the camera to work again by turning of the pi and plugging the camera back in. Inevitably though, I get the timing out error again.

How can I fix this??

Comment: Try asking at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: @tentwentyone. Can you post the code?